# Truthful mechanism for a public project

Tags: game-theory

Consider a community with $n$ residents. The undertaking of a public project with a given cost $C > 0$ is being considered.

Each resident $i$ is simultaneously asked to report his utility $r_i$ in case the public project is undertaken. If the sum of reported utilities $r_1+r_2+\ldots +{r}_n \ge C$, then the public project is implemented; otherwise it is shelved away.

If $r_1+r_2+\ldots +{r}_n \ge C$, then each resident $i$ is asked to pay an amount $p_i$ which is a known function of the vector of reported utilities. Thus, if $u_i$ is $i$'s true utility, his payoff is 
$$u_i - p_i (r_1, \ldots, r_n)$$
if the project is implemented, and it is $0$ otherwise.

How can determine the prices in order to guarantee a truthful mechanism? In other words, is it possible to find a vector of price functions ${p}_1,{p}_2...{p}_n$ such that all residents sincerely report $r_i = u_i$, instead of giving a deceptive report $r_i \ne {u}_i$?

Comment: When you say that $C$ is a random number, do you mean that it is unknown to the participants? Do they know the probability distribution? If that's not what you mean, then take out the word "random".

Comment: Does the city know the true values of $u_i$? If not, how will it ever find out?

Comment: I meant that C is a known positive number,but I didn't explain in.You are right.I will edit the post! The city knows only the values ui that the citizends report , not the true ui . The goal is to choose p1,p2...pn in such a way that the citizens will be forced to report their true ui .

Comment: Are $C$ and $n$ known to the citizens? Do the citizens report simultaneously, without knowing each others' reports?

Comment: C and n are known to the citizens.All citizens report simultaneously , without communicating with each other .

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this problem? If the prices aren't given in advance, then there is a motivation for every citizen to claim $u_i=0$ in order not to lose money.

Comment: I should have mentioned it more clearly , but prices are meant to be given in advance.  However ,  in case u1+u2+...+un < C , noone pays anything. The prices will apply only if u1+u2+...+un >=C.  Despite the fact that prices are known in advance , prices can be a function of ui though. For example , it could be something like pi = ui ! That's equivalent to "you will pay as much as you report , in case u1+u2+...+un>=C"

Comment: Idea 2: 
Every report will belong to [0,C]. ( Even if ui>C, there is no point in reporting anything greater than C).

Provided that noone knows what the others do , it is as if we have n randomly distributed variables X1,X2,...Xn to [0,C].

To assume what the other n-1 citizens are doing, each player i can calulate the distribution of Xtotali=X1 + X2 +...+Xi-1 + Xi+1 +...+Xn.
That's something like a Irwin-Hall distribution , but not exactly.My probability knowledge fails me at the moment.

Then , each player perhaps can use this knowledge to make a decision , but I don't know how...

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example known in the literature as the Groves-Clarke mechanism for the provision of a public good.

Assuming quasi-linear preferences, this mechanism achieves the efficient allocation and truth-telling is the (equilibrium) dominant strategy. However, the mechanism is not budget-balanced; i.e., it may not raise enough money to cover for the cost of the public project.

A result in the literature shows that it is not possible to simultaneously satisfy these three requirements: 1) truthful implementation in dominant strategies; 2) efficient provision; and 3) budget-balance.